# Prepend output from each function named in a bash array with an echo?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, recursion, terminal

I'm looping through arrays:

```
declare -a CommandArray
CommandArray[1]=check_homebrewinstall
CommandArray[2]=check_javainstall
CommandArray[3]=check_gitversioninstall

for i in "${!CommandArray[@]}"; do ${CommandArray[$i]}; done
```

Which prints:

```
✓ Homebrew is installed at /usr/local/bin/brew.
✓ Java is installed at /usr/bin/java.
✓ Latest Git Version: 2.10.1
```

But what to I need to add to the for loop to get to print?:

```
1) ✓ Homebrew is installed at /usr/local/bin/brew.
2) ✓ Java is installed at /usr/bin/java.
3) ✓ Latest Git Version: 2.10.1
```

I want to number each function before its called on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend the index number, `${!CommandArray[$i]}`, you are already saving it as variable `i`, format the output string properly:

```
for i in "${!CommandArray[@]}"; do printf '%s) %s\n' "$i" "$( "${CommandArray[$i]}" )"; done
```

- The command substitution, `"$( "${CommandArray[$i]}" )"`, runs the expansion of `${CommandArray[$i]}` as command
- The output is formatted in the desired format using `printf` pattern '%s) %s\n', with the first string (digit) coming from `i`, and the second from the command substitution

Comment: `"$( "${CommandArray[$i]}" )"`, if we wanted to be proof against the unexpected (`IFS=_` would rather muck things up without the inner quotes, f'rinstance).

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of terseness, I'd consider iterating over values rather than keys, and maintaining a counter:

```
for cmd in "${CommandArray[@]}"; do
  printf '%d) %s\n' "$(( ++idx ))" "$("$cmd")"
done
```

...or, if you trust each command to emit a single line, terminated with a newline, this can be made more efficient by ditching the command substitution and let the command being executed write its results directly to the stdout file descriptor it inherits from the script from which it's invoked:

```
for cmd in "${CommandArray[@]}"; do
  printf '%d) ' "$(( ++idx ))"  # print number with no trailing newline
  "$cmd"                        # ...and count on the command to emit a newline
done
```